# Laser resonator modes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, laser, computational-physics, software

> For a resonator, plot the intensity as a function of time for **(i)** when the modes have identical phases, and **(ii)** when the modes have random phases.

**Attempt**

Here is the equation for intensity (p. 372 of Fundamentals of Photonics):

$$I=\frac{I_0}{1+|r|^2-2|r| \cos \varphi} \tag{1}$$

I believe when the modes have identical phases we must have $\varphi = q2 \pi,$ for some integer $q.$ And when they have random phases we may use a code like `q*rand*pi`.

So, how do we convert equation **(1)** to be a function of time?

There are some versions of equation **(1)** in frequency domain, but they do not take into account the phase. If we plot **(1)** as it is, we will get it as a function of $q:$

[image]

Matlab code used:

```
N=30; I0=5; q=[0:0.1:N]; r=0.75;

phi=q.*2.*pi; % when in-phase
phi2=q.*rand.*pi; % random phase

I1=I0./(1+((abs(r)).^2)-2.*abs(r).*cos(phi));
I2=I0./(1+((abs(r)).^2)-2.*abs(r).*cos(phi2));

plot(q, I1); hold on; plot(q, I2, 'm')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use the final equation from my other answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/254736/laser-resonator-analytic-formula-for-sum-of-modes/255022#255022):

\begin{equation}
E(0,t) = E_0\exp(-i\bar{\omega}t)\frac{\sin[(N/2)\Delta\omega t]}{\sin[(1/2)\Delta\omega t]}.
\end{equation}

This is already a function of time. Now, $I(0,t)\propto |E(0,t)|^{2}$, so just square that function for the intensity (normalize to remove constants if you like).
That will give you the flat phase intensity profile.

In that same derivation I also assume that all of the modes have the same phase. If you remove that assumption and include a random phase term for each of the modes (denoted $\phi_n$ in that derivation) then you should be able to follow the same procedure to get a similar function for the intensity distribution produced when those modes are added. The random phase term can be $e$ to the power of any random imaginary number you like really, but I would recommend that you use something similar to:

\begin{equation}
\phi_\text{n, rand} = \exp\left[-i\omega_n\times\text{randn}\right].
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I have just one more question: we know that the frequency spacing is $\Delta \nu =c/2L,$ so if I want the time window to run from $-1$ to $1,$ how can I define time spacing $\Delta t$ and the span of frequency grid $x$? In the code the vectors would be $$t=[-1 \ :\ \Delta t=1/x \ :\ 1]$$ and $$\nu =[-x=-1/\Delta t\ :\ \Delta \nu \ : \ x=1/\Delta t]$$But this wouldn't work since $x=\Delta \nu$ (we get $\nu=[\Delta\nu:\Delta\nu:\Delta\nu]$). What can I do?

Comment: Starting point (Matlab):

`clear, clc
c = 3e8;
tWindow = 10e-12;
Trt = 12.5e-9;
N=2^12;
dt = tWindow/N;
tau = linspace(-tWindow/2, tWindow/2, N);
L = c*Trt;
lambdaC = 800e-9;
omega = 2*pi*c/lambdaC; 
deltaOmega = 2*pi*c/2*L; 
omega = omega-0.01*omega:deltaOmega:omega+0.01*omega;
field = zeros(1,length(tau));
for i=1:length(omega)
    field = field + exp(1j*omega(i).*tau);
end
field = field./max(abs(field));
figure(1)
plot(1e12.*tau, abs(field.^2))
xlabel('time, ps')
ylabel('Intensity, norm.')`

Comment: In the code above (sorry for terrible formatting) I haven't defined a frequency grid because you don't strictly need one here. If you want to FFT the data and see the spectrum, then you will need to define a frequency grid based on dt, tWindow, and N, and not on the resonator modes themselves (although this might be possible). The code above is just a starting point for this. You can easily adjust it to include the random phase, and to make tWindow = Trt if you like (although you'll need way more grid points).